# Building Web based UI for Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, gui

I am struggling to get some tutorial on building web based UI to interact with smart contract. I found examples on using [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) but it uses `localhost:8545`. However, my understanding is that web based UI or mobile app will run on some server and smartcontract will be remote. How do I build a web based UI to:

1. deposit/transfer ether and
2. interact with smartcontract

I would appreciate clarity and pointers/examples to make mobile app/UI to work with Smartcontract

Comment: its localhost:8545 by default. You can change it by --rpcaddr "address"

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your purpose by using 'web3' & 'solc' package of npm (node.js).
You can know more about them here :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3
https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc

Web3 helps you to connect with an ethereum node & contract deployment And solc is used to compile the contract. You can create UI (web/mobile) which will be hitting some apis written in node.js. Using these two packages you can perform complete functionality of contract development & contract interaction. 
To get a better idea about the web3 apis , read this :
 https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Comment: After going through these links, if you still have any queries, you're most welcome.

Comment: I have seen this and it uses localhost:8545. This works for local private node but when my smartcontract runs on mainnet or testnet in Ethereum blockchain, what should i put in as HttpProvider? web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

Comment: You can define rpc address in geth command as "--rpcaddr 'HostAddress' --rpcport 'portno.'" or can use admin.startRPC(Host, Port). And these host will replace the localhost and port will replace 8545.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one!  I've been struggling a great deal also trying to skill up on front end development.

As you probably know, Mist uses a meteor server to run Meteor client side DAPP frontends.  So I'm currently working through Meteor tutorials.

For Meteor in general, Ethereum's own Fabian Vogelsteller 'wrote the book' which I recommend downloading from Amazon:[Building Single-page Web Apps with Meteor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SVBFBJU)

More specifically you want to look at [Dapp using Meteor](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Dapp-using-Meteor) and get cozy with the various Ethereum Meteor packages that it links to which include standard Mist styles and tooling.

I'm currently messing around with all that but still don't have a functional integrated front end yet.